# Restify req.getLogger is not a function

Tags: node.js, prototypal-inheritance, restify, bunyan

How do I install bunyan logger so that on the routes they can get children of bunyan for their own loggers?

Attempt:

```
import * as restify from 'restify';
import {createLogger} from 'bunyan';

let app = restify.createServer();

app.use(restify.queryParser());
app.use(restify.bodyParser());

app.on('after', restify.auditLogger({
    log: createLogger({
        name: 'audit',
        stream: process.stdout
    })
}));

app.get('/foo', (req, res, next) => {
    req.getLogger('foo').info('bar');
    res.json({});
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    console.info('%s listening at %s', app.name, app.url);
});
```

`req.getLogger` should work as per http://restify.com/#getloggercomponent, but maybe there's an `app.use` step also required, but not mentioned in the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I did it in a recent application.

```
var Bunyan = require('bunyan');
var log = new Bunyan();

var server = restify.createServer({
    log: log
});
```

Then, wherever you have access to the request object you just use it like this.

```
req.log.error({req_id: req.id()}, "There was an error...");
```

Comment: Thanks, actually `createLogger({log: createLogger({name: 'foo'})})` also works. Following your answer I added this issue: https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/1011

Comment: The docs were wrong, that issue I created catalyzed the doc change.